# Script to fix bunch of FBXs?

Tags: scripting, .fbx

I have over a hundred game animations that share the same issue. My armature object in each of the files has a unique name but I need it to be "Armature".
So now I need to open every FBX, rename my armatures as "Armature" and resave each FBX with the same settings, and the same name. I wonder if the scripting can help me to automate this process? Cause resaving 124 files seems wrong ToT And I am a total noob in scripting. Perhaps anybody can help with the issue?